# Recommendation of technologies/languages (or SAAS that is recommended) to build a full-stack web application

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for advise as to what platform or if not a platform, what technologies for the different parts of the stack you'd suggest.

This web application will have the following function:  taking in parameters (not very many), and performing a calculation to enable the user to see what is needed (it is a safety product).  The data may include users having accounts, the data affiliated with the calculations (beyond the parameters being passed).  It is somewhat of a glorified calculator in a technical field.

I believe that it will be a relatively simple application (although I think our Community will find it helpful).  I just want to be sure to explore all options up-front.

Thank you for any insight.  If you feel this question is better suited for a different message board, I'd love it if you could pass that along.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else finds it helpful but it looks like Firebase (Google's backend) may be a solid solution.  From a front-end basis, I'm looking at angular and for the BLL java or C#.